# Craft 3 beta nginx config

Tags: nginx

I have a Craft 3 beta project working fine on my local `laravel/homestead` box using nginx, however when I push to Heroku using their `heroku-php-nginx` build pack I get nginx (not Craft) 404s when trying to access the `/admin` area.

My `Procfile` looks like this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C deploy/nginx.conf public/
```

and my `deploy/nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This setup works fine with Craft 3:

[Nginx-Craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft)